# Identifying spaces between commas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to identify if theres a space between a number and comma then that number is invalid. So if the number has more or less than 2 decimal places and/or white spaces in between the commas then it is INVALID but if it has no whitespaces in between the commas and has 2 decimal places then it it a VALID number. That's why the first number in Line 1 is VALID

There's two methods, I prefer to work on method 2 but I thought if I put two methods it might help any of you to add on

```
#-----------Method 1------------------------------------------
res = 0
outfile = "output2.txt"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
index = 0
invalid_string = "INVALID"
valid_string = "VALID"
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        carrera = ''
        index = index + 1
        print("Line {}: ".format(index), end='')
        baconFile.write("Line {}:  ".format(index))
        number_list = line.strip().split(',')
        for number in number_list:
            if len(number.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
                #res += 1
##              print("VALID")

                carrera = valid_string 
            if len(number.split('.')[-1]) != 2:
                #res += 1
                carrera = invalid_string
            if len(number.split(',')[-1]) == " ":                         #checking for whitespace 
                carrera = invalid_string

            print (carrera, end=' ')
            baconFile.write(carrera + " ")
        print('\n', end='')
        baconFile.write('\n')
baconFile.close()
#-----------Method 2------------------------------------------

res = 0
outfile = "output2.txt"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
index = 0
invalid_string = "INVALID"
valid_string = "VALID"
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        index = index + 1
        o = "Line {}: ".format(index)
        number_list = line.strip().split(',')
        for x in number_list:
            if len(x.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
                o += valid_string + " "
            if len(x.split('.')[-1]) != 2:
                o += invalid_string + " "
            if len(x.split(',')[-1]) == " ":
                o += valid_string + " "
```

Here's my list of numbers in Text.file:

```
1,1.02, 123.0005

1.02, 1.02 , 1.02
```

Expected:

```
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID

Line 2: VALID INVALID INVALID (since there's spaces between the last number that's why it is INVALID)
```

ACTUAL:

```
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID

Line 2: VALID INVALID VALID
```

Comment: why would `Line 1`  first number would be invalid?

Comment: `1,` should be valid since it doesn't start with a whitespace, I have assumed that and  tried to come up with an answer @Slashx43 check it out

Comment: @SebastienD sorry I forgot to mention which numbers qualify as VALID or INVALID I updated my question

Comment: Thanks for the update @Slashx43 I have updated my conditions in the answer according to your new input, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the strings with `,` and decide if the string is valid or invalid based on whether the string stars with a whitespace

```
#Open the files
with open('file.txt') as fp:

    #Extract out non-empty lines from file
    lines = [line for line in fp.readlines() if line.strip()]
    res = []

    #Iterate over the lines
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):

        #Number is valid if it doesn't start with a whitespace, has a decimal part and the decimal part is two digits long
        res = ['VALID' if not item.startswith(' ') and '.' in item and len(item.split('.')[1]) == 2 else 'INVALID' for item in line.split(',')]

        #Print the result
        print("Line {}: {}".format(idx+1, ' '.join(res)))
```

The output will be

```
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID
Line 2: VALID INVALID INVALID
```

Comment: I see how it works but when I put that in my code it doesn't print out the Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID. It just says theres an Invalid syntax which is the last quotation marks in the print statement. What's the purpose of the f inside the print statement? if I delete the f then it prints out:

 Line {idx+1}: {' '.join(res)}

Line {idx+1}: {' '.join(res)}

Comment: aah okay, what python version are you using? Those are f-strings, a new way to format string but for python3.6 and above, anyways I have reverted to older string.format which should work for you @Slashx43 You can try again and it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
line="1,1.02, 123.0005"
reslt=line.split(",")
Res=" "
for i in reslt:
    if " "in i:
        line1="INVALID "
    else:
        line1="VALID "
    Res +="".join(line1)
print("line1:"+Res)
```

READ from file :

```
nbline

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
        reslt=line.split(",")
        Res=" "
        for i in reslt:
            if " "in i:
                line1="INVALID "
            else:
                line1="VALID "
            Res +="".join(line1)
    nbline = nbline+1
    print("line {}:{}".format(nbline,Res))
```

output:
    line1: VALID VALID INVALID

Comment: This is helpful but I am getting the list of numbers from a text file, not from the code itself.

Comment: i already update the code and i added a part to read form file

Answer (score 0):

With `decimal.Decimal` object, you can retrieve the exponent, which somehow tells you the number of decimal places ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects)):

```
import decimal
o += " ".join(['INVALID' if x[0] == ' ' or decimal.Decimal(x).as_tuple().exponent != -2 else 'VALID' for x in line.split(',')])
```

**Output**

```
#with line = "1,1.02, 123.0005"
'Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID'

#with line = "1.02, 1.02 , 1.02"
'Line 2: VALID INVALID INVALID'
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension based on splitting on commas, and a little string trickery would be much simpler:

```
line="1,1.02, 123.0005"
result = " ".join("IN"*(" " in s)+"VALID" for s in line.split(","))
print(result) # VALID VALID INVALID
```

Comment: I think readability/understand-ability matters more than reducing the number of lines of code. The `"IN"*(" " in s)` is plain ol' witchcraft.

Comment: @Toothpick Anemone, I agree with you on the legibility concern.  It is sometimes hard to exorcise the Python Warlock in me :)

Comment: @AlainT. thanks but I need to read/write the numbers off from a text file and not from the numbers in the code itself

Comment: Since your code shows that you already know how to read lines from a file, I didn't believe it was relevant to repeat that part. I also felt that it would burry the actual solution under boiler plate code.